# VScode load image very slow

Tags: visual-studio-code

## Description

I'm recently involved in a project that requires producing images (mainly .PNG) very frequently and I noticed that VScode is experiencing hard time in opening my generated image. For an image with size of 1MB, it takes 2 seconds, 3MB -> 5 seconds, larger the image is, slower the opening does. Is this the natural build-in "feature" for VScode? (I just switched from Atom to VScode, while Atom opens images without wait, which allows me to compare two images intuitively)

## Version

Version: 1.74.2

Date: 2022-12-20T10:26:09.430Z (1 mo ago)

## OS

macOS Monterey
Version 12.6

Comment: Is it slow to open the files using other applications? Could it just be something like a slow disk drive?

Comment: @user Nah, it's fine with other apps. and it's also ok for vscode to open scripts/files.